# Why is DataView by default in Big Endian?

Tags: javascript, endianness

Could someone explain, why is DataView using the byte order `Big Endian`? While our computers are working with `Little Endian`. Also ARM processors.

Typed Arrays like `Uint32Array()` already use `Little Endian`. In my opinion this is correctly.

```
// DataView (Big Endian)
const dataview = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4));
dataview.setUint32(0, 42);
console.log(new Uint8Array(dataview.buffer).toString());
// result: 0,0,0,42

// Typed Array (Little Endian)
const typearray = new Uint32Array([42]);
console.log(new Uint8Array(typearray.buffer).toString());
// result: 42,0,0,0
```

I expected little endian for number types. It's not consistent.
I know the optional argument of DataView methods for `litleEndian`. 
But my question is: Why is this not set by default?

Answer (score 0):

This is the prototype for the setUint32 method as defined by the ECMAscript standard:

`24.2.4.20 DataView.prototype.setUint32 ( byteOffset, value [ , littleEndian ] )`( https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-dataview-constructor ).

Whether the value is stored as little endian or big endian is defined by the optional 3rd parameter, whose default value is **defined by the standard** as false (store as big endian).

Big endian is the default byte ordering for all TCP/IP network protocols and it is not rare at all.

Comment: And why are the typed arrays in little endian? If that systems are oriented on web protocols like TCP/IP (big endian)?

Comment: In which cases are the bytes of a TCP / IP transmission processed directly? Usually you communicate at a higher level. The data you'll receive have nothing to do with the endian of TCP/IP. I can not comprehend that.

Comment: I already knew the optional property `littleEndian`. I just do not unterstood / unterstand why is big endian the default. And why are TypedArrays by default little endian. I'm working on embedded systems (ARM) storing numbers in little endian. Also the communication (CAN) is in little endian. And at last the TypedArrays are in little endian. I just wondered why the DataView is such different.

Comment: TypedArrays are not little endian by default. They actually use the endianness of the underlying operating system. Nowadays there aren't many systems being made with big endian chips anymore, let alone one that runs javascript. So that's why it might *seem* like TypedArrays use little endian by default.

Comment: I think that OP's question is meant to highlight the inconsistency in the standard here, that one part of the API uses the underlying endianness of the platform, while another part of the API arbitrarily defaults to big endian, where one might think it should also default to the underlying endianness of the platform to be consistent with typed arrays.